# Xamarin swap single ResourceDictionary programmatically

Tags: xamarin.forms, themes

I'm currently trying to get custom themes working with a Xamarin App and I've found a way I can make this work the way I want it to, but it seems terribly inefficient, so figured I'd ask to see if you lot had better answers.

So here's the issue, I want to build a screen where users can change themes (there will be many, not just light/dark), and I want to swap out the current theme ResourceDictionary and replace it with the new chosen theme's ResourceDictionary. The problem is I also want the App to have other global ResourceDictionaries, and every tutorial I find recommends calling Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear(), but that then gets rid of my other ResourceDictionaries.

Here is my Xaml, I don't want to replace DefaultButton.xaml or LinkButton.xaml, I only want to replace LightTheme.xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myTestApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/ResourceDictionaries/LightTheme.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/DefaultButton.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/LinkButton.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then in my App class I have

```
public void ChangeTheme(ThemeOptions theme)
{
    ResourceDictionary newRes;
    switch (theme)
    {
        case ThemeOptions.Light:
            newRes = new LightTheme();
            break;
        case ThemeOptions.Dark:
            newRes = new DarkTheme();
            break;
        default:
            newRes = new LightTheme();
            break;
    }
    
    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
    Resources.Add(newRes);
}
```

Now obviously the DefaultButton.xaml and LinkButton.xaml ResourceDictionaries have now been cleared. I can add them back, but it seems terribly inefficient over just finding and removing the Theme. Is there an easy way to simply identify the ResourceDictionary I want to overwrite and replace that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I may have discovered the answer to my problem, but not to the original question. I created a "BundledSiteStyles" ResourceDictionary, and simply added that as a MergedDictionary to each of my themes. Then the App.xaml file only loads a theme and all the styling comes along for the ride.

So my App.xaml has no ResourceDictionaries added, then programmatically on startup I get the active theme and call my ChangeTheme function

```
public void ChangeTheme(ThemeOptions theme)
{
    switch (theme)
    {
        case ThemeOptions.Light:
            Resources = new LightTheme();
            break;
        case ThemeOptions.Dark:
            Resources = new DarkTheme();
            break;
        default:
            Resources = new LightTheme();
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is my LightTheme.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="myTestApp.Themes.ResourceDictionaries.LightTheme">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/BundledSiteStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Color x:Key="LinkButtonBackgroundColor">Transparent</Color>
    <Color x:Key="LinkButtonTextColor">Blue</Color>
    <!-- Add more colours here -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And here is my BundledSiteStyles.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="myTestApp.Styles.BundledSiteStyles">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Add global ResourceDictionaries Here -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultButton.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="LinkButton.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If there is a more efficient/correct way of doing this, please let me know, but for now it seems to work.

Comment: That works fine. Wouldn't need to put BundledSiteStyles reference on each page, if [set App `Resources` to a MergedDictionary that includes it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66423775/199364).

Comment: I tried using it as a MergedDictionary, but it wouldn't work when I'd need to programmatically change my theme. The problem being that I'd need to clear the MergedDictionaries in order to remove the no longer used theme.

Comment: It does work programmatically. When changing theme, you would do `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();`, then create the entire MergedDictionary, by adding BOTH the theme AND `BundledSiteStyles`, similar to the link I gave.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned this in the original post, that I wanted to avoid doing this because it was terribly inefficient and doesn't scale well.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that detail. I'll comment that it is pointless to be concerned about "inefficient", until you encounter a specific situation where the performance is actually a problem. How often does user change themes? How much time is acceptable? How long does this technique actually take in practice? A second? As for scaling, you can probably make a single merged dictionary that holds all the not-changing resources. To make it faster to re-create the final merged dictionary. Regardless, however long it takes, it will be MUCH more efficient than forcing that merge in each page load!!

Comment: Actually, I have an idea of what you can do. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the themes have the same keys, you can replace it by iterating through its keys, and replacing those entries in the merged dictionary.

I haven't tested, but should be something like this:

```
var resources = Application.Current.Resources;

foreach (var key in themes.Keys)
    resources[key] = themes[key];
```

Comment: Tested it and works perfectly. Love the simplicity of it. Note: When defining a ResourceDirctionary Theme in Xaml you need a partial class code behind file and you need to call InitialiseComponent() in the constructor in order for the xaml theme file entries to load when you instantiate a resourcedictionary instance of it in code.